# How to add retries to port binding in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, apache-karaf

Intermittently I observe that my karaf service restart fails due to the error while port binding. This is because the port is not released by OS yet. So, adding couple of retries would fix this for me.

So question is - How can I configure jetty to make it retry port binding in case of failures.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in Jetty.

Feel free to request an enhancement to Jetty at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: Added a issue - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3037. Thanks @Joakim